# Connection Algorithm with Constraints

Tags: algorithm, connection, constraints

I have block categories A, B, C, ... and each category has blocks. all blocks in each category have ports p0, p1, p2, ... and have constraints to connect as:

- A: a0, a1, a2, ...

  - p0: B, C
  - p1: B
  - p2: B, C
  - p3: C
- B: b0, b1, b2, ...

  - p0: A
- C: c0, c1, c2, ...

  - p0: A
- D: d0, d1, d2, ...

  - p0: B
  - p1: C

With the above information, what algorithm do I have to use to obtain every combinations of all blocks that their ports are fully connected?

for example, if we have

[image]

then the resultant combinations will be:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about what you mean by "blocks" and "ports?" Could you show an example of how these items connect right now?

Comment: I've added an example to the question! Thank you!

Comment: You only care that all of the a's ports are filled?

Comment: No, all blocks' ports have to be filled. Of course we assume that the given constraints meet the consistency.